# Make a database connection to Sage Abra Suite

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

I want to create a CSV file from our Sage Abra Suite database using C#. At this point I am just trying to make a connection to it and having difficulty to create one and to test it.

I have a Visual Studio 2010 installed, and the table that I want to access is resided on the server (called it Server1). As far as I know the database that the Sage Abra uses is VisualFoxPro

So I need help right now to how to create the database connection and testing the connection in C#.

Comment: From the Sage Abra marketing site, **"Its flexible design features your choice of database platforms, including SQL, MSDE, or Visual FoxPro"** Is there a reason you believe it to be Visual FoxPro instead of some other database?

Comment: that's what the support guys say. And the databases end with .dbf

Comment: Then [Accessing Visual FoxPro Data in Visual Studio .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977092%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), should be a good place to start.

Comment: I have read that but the 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro' does not show up on my list

Comment: The [Visual FoxPro ODBC Driver not included in MDAC 2.6 and later](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/277772) includes links to download the relevant files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using a connection string

```
   // Build the connection string
      string connectionString = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source= myServer;Collating Sequence=general";

      // Create the connection
      OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

      // Open the connection
      connection.Open();
```